# Oracle data type for short, fixed-length binary data

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

What is an efficient data type to store a small, fixed-length array of bytes (e.g., an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)) in an Oracle table?

I would like to avoid `LOB` types, as they are optimized for "[large blocks of unstructured data](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i3237)", or transferring the burden of [encoding/decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) the binary payload to the application in order to use a `CHAR`-based data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing variable length binary data you may use RAW datatype. It has a Maximum size of 2000 bytes. You can also specify a maximum size limit lower thant the default one.